# Image resize function in codeigniter failed to resize the image

Tags: codeigniter

I have the following code:

```
if($this->upload->do_upload())
                {

                    $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
                    $configer =  array(
                      'image_library'   => 'gd2',
                      'source_image'    =>  $data['upload_data']['full_path'],
                      'maintain_ratio'  =>  TRUE,
                      'width'           =>  1024,
                      'height'          =>  350,
                    );
                    $this->image_lib->clear();
                    $this->image_lib->initialize($configer);
                    $this->image_lib->resize();

                    $upl_filename = $data['upload_data']['file_name'];
                    $imageUpdateData = array($entity.'_image' => $upl_filename);
                    $this->db->where($entity.'_id',$id);
                    $queryImage = $this->db->update($entity,$imageUpdateData);


                    $image1_success = 1;
                    $image1_msg = "$entity updated successfully";

                }
```

My image is getting uploaded successfully. Even the `$this->image_lib->resize();` is working fine (since I tried to print a message when the function works).

But, the image is not getting resized. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: track the error on `$this->image_lib->resize();` here by using `$this->image_lib->display_errors();` https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/image_lib.html#processing-methods

Comment: The $this->image_lib->display_errors(); is totally blank. There is no error.

Comment: Is the PHP GD library installed as CodeIgniter relies on this extension being installed. You can check by creating a PHP info page using the `phpinfo()` function and looking for GD.

Comment: Your missing your file input field name here example `$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')`